# FlowCoverView How to force the view to move to a given image programmatically?

Tags: iphone, coverflow

I'm using FlowCoverView, an open source (and AppStore compliant) alternative to Apple's cover flow (you can find it here http://chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.m)

I'd like to modify the code so that you can force the view to start from (or to move to) a specific image programmatically, given its index.
I'm not being successful though :(

Solution:

```
-(void)goToIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index<[self numTiles])
    {
        offset = index;
        [self draw];
        //[delegate flowCover:self highlighted:index];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the mid image in draw method in flowcover class.

Comment: Great! I was moving in the animate direction (setting the offset and startPos vars and then launching startAnimation) to have a smoother effect (still have problems with that), but your solution is more straightforward...

Comment: for this you need to edit and touch begin and touch end event.

Comment: I also need the solution, can you give a bit explaination? Mitesh Khatri